# Start TCPListener after reboot using .bashrc

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian, tcplistener

I'm trying to start a TCPListener after I reboot my system. I'm using .bashrc and opening a terminal after reboot using:

```
echo "@lxterminal" | sudo tee -a /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

and placing my command on .bashrc as

```
echo "/home/pi/startup.sh" | sudo tee -a ~/.bashrc
```

As you can see I'm using Raspbian. Right now I'm getting a

```
Unable to start TCPListener on <ip>:<port>
```

when I run it trough .bashrc but when I run it manually there is no error.

Comment: Do you need to have a new listener for each terminal session started by `pi` user? If so, your startup script might need to change (only one application can bind to a port at a time). Futhermore, you'll require root privileges if binding to a port lower than 1024. If you don't need a new listener for each terminal session, I suggest adding it to `rc.local` instead. Worst case you can have a crontab to trigger the script with an `@reboot /home/pi/startup.sh`. Perhaps full debug logs and contents of `autostart` will be useful if the above doesn't help.

Comment: I just need the process to start once after startup.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence i ended up using a cron job `@restart`.